# create different document libraries in different content databases

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I want to create multiple document libraries under the same site collection in sharepoint. However i would like to be able to specify different content databases for these document libraries - is that possible?

Example.
Site - TestSite has multiple content databases Content_1 and Content_2.
TestSite has two document libraries Documents_A and Documents_B.

Is there a way i can have Documents_A stored in Content_1 and Documents_B in Content_2?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, a web application can have multiple content databases, but a site collection can only be stored on a single database.

You can choose the database in which a site will be stored by using [this trick](http://www.etechplanet.com/blog/create-and-associate-multiple-content-databases-with-a-sharepoint-web-application.aspx).

Comment: marking this as the answer in so much as 'a site collection can only be stored on a single database'. basically what we are trying to achieve is not possible. thanks for the feedback